# Pattern Recognition, Bishop - (Linear) Discriminant Functions 4.1

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

Please refer "[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)" - Bishop, page 182.

I am struggling to visualize the intuition behind equations 4.6 & 4.7. I am presenting my understanding of section 4.1.1 using the diagram:

[image]

---

***Pls. Note***: I have used $x_{\perp}$ and $x_{p}$ interchangeably.

Equations 4.6, 4.7 from book: $$\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x_{\perp}} + \textit{r}\mathbf{\frac{w}{\Vert{w}\Vert}} \tag {4.6}$$ Muiltiplying both sides of this result by $\mathbf{w^{T}}$ and adding $w_{0}$, and making use of $y(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{w^{T}x} + w_{0}$ and $y(\mathbf{x_{\perp}}) = \mathbf{w^{T}x_{\perp}} + w_{0} = 0$, we have $$r = \frac{y(\mathbf{x})}{\Vert{\mathbf{w}}\Vert} \tag{4.7}$$

> ***Questions***:
>
> 1. Is $y(\mathbf{x})$ the (orthogonal) projection of $(\mathbf{w^{T}x} + w_{0})$ along $\mathbf{w}$, the weight vector?
> 2. Are the lengths normalized to express them as multiples of unit vector $\mathbf{\frac{{w}}{\Vert{w}\Vert}}$. If so, can the distance
>      $r = $$\frac{y(\mathbf{x})}{\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert}$ exceed 1.
> 3. Given that, $$ y(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{w^{T}x} + w_{0}$$ i.e. $y(\cdot)$ has two parts: $\textit{orthogonal component above/ below}$
>      decision boundary, and the $\textit{bias}$. And so, I'm calculating
>      $y(\cdot)$ as:
>
> $$y(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{\frac{w^{T}x}{\Vert{w}\Vert}} + \frac{w_{0}}{\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert}$$ while the book gets it as:
>   $$y(\mathbf{x}) = {\frac{y(\mathbf{x})}{\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert}} + \frac{w_{0}}{\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert}$$
>   I am struggling to visualize how do we get the first term in the equation above (in book, eqn. 4.7)

Alternatively, presenting my doubt/argument w.r.t. to book eqns 4.6 & 4.7; by substituting  $r$ (eq. 4.7) into eq. 4.6 we get:
$$\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x_{p}} + y(\mathbf{x}) \qquad {(\Vert{\mathbf{w}}\Vert^{2} = \mathbf{w})}$$

which again seems to be incorrect - by triangle rule of vector addition.

> Given the context, where am I losing track? Request your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, $y(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+w_0$; it is a scalar.  The dot product $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}$ is $\|\mathbf{w}\|$ times the length of the projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto $\mathbf{w}$.  $w_0$ in your figure would be negative, and has the property that $y(\mathbf{x})=0$ whenever $\mathbf{x}$ is on the decision boundary.
2. No normalization appears to be necessary.  Certainly $r$ can be arbitrarily large (either positive or negative), when $\mathbf{x}$ is far away from the decision boundary.
3. As mentioned previously, the first term is actually a length from the origin; the bias serves to shift this so that $y$ itself is the orthogonal (scalar) component [up to scaling by $\|w\|$...But that's what we're out to show when we pass from Eq(4.6) to (4.7)].

The text's approach is to decompose $\mathbf{x}$ into components relative to the decision boundary: $\mathbf{x}_{\perp}$ on the boundary, and *something* perpendicular to the boundary.  Being perpendicular to the boundary, it is in the direction of $\mathbf{w}$, but we don't know how far, so they introduce its length as the unknown $r$.  (There's some standard geometry stuff here that could also get us to the conclusion, but I'll explain their approach.)

Now, as mentioned before, $y$ is zero on the boundary, so they have $y(\mathbf{x}_{\perp})=0$.  And now, just to fill in some of the details of what they say,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{x}_{\perp} + r \frac{\mathbf{w}}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}\\
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+w_0 &= \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_{\perp}+w_0 + r \frac{ \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w} }{ \|\mathbf{w}\| } \\
y(\mathbf{x}) &= y(\mathbf{x}_{\perp}) + r \frac{\|\mathbf{w}\|^2}{\|\mathbf{w}\|} \\
y(\mathbf{x}) &= 0 + r \|\mathbf{w}\|,
\end{align*}$$
and so $r=y(\mathbf{x})/\|\mathbf{w}\|$ as desired.

[I'm not sure what you meant in your last few lines; at least some of it seems to have been a typo?  Feel free to follow up.]

---

EDIT: Regarding your addition about substituting $r$, you should get $$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_{\perp}+y(\mathbf{x})\frac{\mathbf{w}}{\|\mathbf{w}\|^2},$$
but $\|\mathbf{w}\|^2$ is not equal to $\mathbf{w}$; the former is a scalar, and the latter a vector!  Rewriting, we have
$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_{\perp}+\frac{y(\mathbf{x})}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}\frac{\mathbf{w}}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}.$$
This now looks correct: from the origin, go to $\mathbf{x}_{\perp}$, then along the unit vector $\mathbf{w}/\|\mathbf{w}\|$ for a distance of $y(\mathbf{x})/\|\mathbf{w}\|$ (which, per your bubble3, is the correct distance).

Comment: (1 of 2 ) ..Thanks for the effort. I updated the image. A few doubts: **Point 1**. "No", and "2nd sentence": the core of my doubt. Applying function f(.) we get (ref black arrow along w): y(x) = w^T(shift) + -w_0(scale)$. w.r.t. this eqn: if *-w_0 is distance of decision boundary from origin, what's is the second part - doubt presented by B4 in the diagram (pls. ignore B1 for a moment). Also, shouldn't the *normalised projection of x along w be (w^T.x)/ ||w||. You've mentioned it as (w^T.x)*||w||. Kindly add a line on this. *B*=> bubble

Comment: (2 of 2) **Point 2** ref. 2nd sentence: If *No normalisation appears to be necessary* then what the purpose of division by ||w||. Rest of algebra for **Point 3** is pretty clear now (though intuition is missing - detailed in prev comment); this seemingly simple concept has kept me engaged for last 2 days.

Comment: BTW, I'm accepting your answer as it clears my doubt about eqn. 4.7. I (partially) agree with your points 1 & 2. Regards.

Comment: What is $f$?  Again, $y$ is a scalar, not a vector.  w^Tx/|w| is B1, not B4.  B4 is y(x)*|w|.  Reread the last part of point 1: I have said the projection, B1, is w^T.x/|w|, not w^T.x*|w|.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your noble time and effort. *f* is simply (w^T.x/|w|). Misunderstanding size of B1 was the root cause of my doubt. Regards.